# Angular Material Dialog - Factory Pattern

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, modal-dialog, abstraction

I need to create a DRY modal abstraction using the angular material dialog component and wanted to use a factory function, creating a new material dialog with: `new Modal(component, config, data)`

I would like:

- a modal "model" to handle the configuration of properties
- a modal "service" to handle the opening and closing of the dialog
- any component passed into the shared modal component
- "action" buttons can be passed into the modal as templates

> function signature I'd like to use to create these modals/dialogs:

```js
  openModal(): void {
    const testData = { name: "dummy name", address: "dummy address" };
    
    this.modalService.createModal(
      new Modal(
        // component to inject:
        ChildComponent,
        {
          // modal options:
          title: "the custom title"
        },
        {
          // modal config:
          data: { item: testData },
          hasBackdrop: false,
          autoFocus: false
        },
        {
          // modal action "templates":
          actionsRight: componentInstance.instance.modalFooterRightRef,
          actionsLeft: componentInstance.instance.modalFooterLeftRef,
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Can this be done with a material dialog?

---

Here's a stackblitz of the current effort: https://angular-dialog-abstraction.stackblitz.io 
There's a feature module containing the implementation and a shared module for the abstraction.

Currently the modal:
√ opens 
√ injects the component 
√ receives data as expected 
x works as expected: there is no title or action buttons.

---

Modal Model

```js
import { Type } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { ModalOptions, ModalTemplates } from "../interfaces/modal";
import { ModalSizeOptions } from "../enums/modal-size-options.enum";

export class Modal {
  static defaultModalOptions: ModalOptions = {
    cancel: true,
    close: false,
    footer: true,
    size: ModalSizeOptions.MEDIUM,
    title: "Attention"
  };

  static defaultModalConfig: MatDialogConfig = {
    data: null,
    ariaDescribedBy: null,
    ariaLabel: null,
    ariaLabelledBy: null,
    autoFocus: true,
    backdropClass: null,
    closeOnNavigation: false,
    componentFactoryResolver: null,
    direction: "ltr",
    disableClose: true,
    hasBackdrop: false,
    height: "",
    id: "",
    maxHeight: null,
    maxWidth: null,
    minHeight: null,
    minWidth: null,
    panelClass: "",
    position: { top: "", bottom: "", left: "", right: "" },
    restoreFocus: true,
    role: null,
    scrollStrategy: null,
    viewContainerRef: null,
    width: ""
  };

  static defaultTemplates: ModalTemplates = {
    error: null,
    header: null,
    content: null,
    actionsLeft: null,
    actionsRight: null
  };

  public component: Type<any>;
  public options = Modal.defaultModalOptions;
  public dialog = Modal.defaultModalConfig;
  public templates: ModalTemplates;

  constructor(
    component: Type<any>,
    options?: ModalOptions,
    dialog?: MatDialogConfig,
    templates?: ModalTemplates
  ) {
    this.component = component;
    this.options = options
      ? Object.assign({}, Modal.defaultModalOptions, options)
      : Modal.defaultModalOptions;
    this.dialog = dialog
      ? Object.assign({}, Modal.defaultModalConfig, dialog)
      : Modal.defaultModalConfig;
    this.templates = templates
      ? Object.assign({}, Modal.defaultTemplates, templates)
      : Modal.defaultTemplates;
  }
}
```

Modal Component

```js
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Modal } from "../../models/modal";

@Component({
  selector: "app-modal",
  styleUrls: ["./modal.component.css"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ modal.options.title }}</h1>
        <button mat-icon-button mat-dialog-close="true">
          <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </header>

      <mat-dialog-content>
        <ng-template #component></ng-template>
      </mat-dialog-content>

      <div *ngIf="modal.options.footer">
        <footer class="flex justify-between w-full">
          <div class="modalFooterLeft">
            <mat-dialog-actions>
              <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="modal.templates.actionsLeft"
              ></ng-container>
            </mat-dialog-actions>
          </div>

          <div class="modalFooterRight">
            <mat-dialog-actions>
              <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="modal.templates.actionsRight"
              ></ng-container>
              <button
                *ngIf="modal.options.cancel"
                mat-button
                mat-dialog-close
                cdkFocusInitial
              > Cancel </button>

              <button
                 *ngIf="modal.options.close"
                 mat-button
                 mat-dialog-close
              > Close </button>
            </mat-dialog-actions>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() public modal: Modal;

  constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Modal Service

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { Modal } from "../models/modal";

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public createModal(modal?: Modal): any {
    return this.openModal(modal.component, modal.dialog);
  }

  private openModal(component: any, config: MatDialogConfig): any {
    return this.dialog.open(component, config);
  }
}
```

Example of passing the action buttons as templates from the child component that is injected into the modal component:

```js
<ng-template #actionsRight>
  <button
    mat-button color="primary"
    [disabled]="f.pristine || !f.valid"
    [loading]="this.state.loading"
    (click)="createItem()"
  >Create</button>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #actionsLeft>
  <button
    mat-button color="primary"
    [disabled]="f.pristine || !f.valid"
    [loading]="this.state.loading"
    (click)="deleteItem()"
  >Delete</button>
</ng-template>
```

Really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean by "real" material dialog. In real material dialog we have to add those buttons manually

Comment: @yurzui - There is no title, there are no action buttons and pressing the escape key to exit does not work. The stackblitz example should reflect that. I'll adjust the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you're opening `ChildComponent` directly.

```
this.openModal(modal.component, modal.dialog);
```

If you want to use `ModalComponent` as a base wrapper for all dynamically created dialogs then you should open that component instead.

**modal.service.ts**

```
this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
  ...modal.dialog,
  data: modal
});
```

Here I'm passing dialog related options to MatDialog as well as the whole your `Modal` model as a `data`. This `data` will be available in `ModalComponent` though DI.

**modal.component.ts**

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
      
  constructor(
    ...
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public modal: Modal
  ) {}
```

Now, we're inside ModalComponent where we can dynamically create passed `ChildComponent` into `<ng-template #component></ng-template>` by using low-level Angular API:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("component", { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  componentTarget: ViewContainerRef;

  actionsLeft: TemplateRef<any>;
  actionsRight: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private inj: Injector,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public modal: Modal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      this.modal.component
    );
    const componentRef = this.componentTarget.createComponent(
      factory,
      null,
      Injector.create({
        providers: [
          {
            provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
            useValue: this.modal.dialog.data
          }
        ],
        parent: this.inj
      })
    );
```

After that you can event action buttons defined as templates in ChildComponent:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  actionsLeft: TemplateRef<any>;
  actionsRight: TemplateRef<any>;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    const componentRef = this.componentTarget.createComponent(
      factory,
      ...
    );
    this.actionsLeft = componentRef.instance.actionsLeftRef;
    this.actionsRight = componentRef.instance.actionsRightRef;
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialog-abstraction-qwetgy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Ffeature%2Fparent%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)**